# Adding backgroundimage to my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using this code to add a background image to my tableview

```
myTable.backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]] autorelease];
```

on the internet they say this code works, but it's not working for me
can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if its a UITableViewController, as I believe it is, do this:

```
[myTable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]];
```

or you can do (on a non-table view controller)

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]];
```

or on viewDidLoad you can do:

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
```

but thats a bit messy - I prefer to use `setBackgroundColor:`

Comment: is it possible to do this in the appdelegate? so things wouldn't be messy at all

Comment: but you can set the background of the navigation controller `self.navigationController.backgroundColor = ...` and then make every subsequent view transparent? bit of a faff though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that backgroundview for tableview is a UIView, not a UIImage. So you need to create a view, easiest way is to use a UIImageView. For example this would put your splash screen image as the background view for the table in a UITableViewController...

```
    UIImage *backImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"];
UIImageView *backImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backImage];
self.tableView.backgroundView = backImageView;
```

The methods mentioned above are pre the introduction of tableview property backgroundview in 3.2

edit - dear god I was obviously having a coffee deficit today :) The op is indeed using a UIImageView! The only thing I can think is that he is targeting a pre 3.2 platform...